# display:table property not working in IE7

Tags: css

In Asp.net MVC3 the following error occurs.
I use The following CSS in my project. It works in IE8 and IE9 but not working in IE7.
I want the solution for it. Help me for this issue

CSS is:

```
.divRow
{
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}


.AttlistHeading
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 190px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; /* border-right:1px solid #cccccc;*/
}
.divCellHeading
{
    width: 378px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

.divcell
{
    /*display:table-footer-group;*/
    width: 378px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: IE7 doesn't support display:table

Comment: Thanks and what is the solution for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `display:table;`  on the parent div, you should have `display:table-row;` and `display:table-column;` - elements in it.

`display:table` is not supported by ie7 http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: Thanks and explain with eaxmple

Answer (score 0):

if you use `display:table;` on the parent dic, you should have `display:table-row;` and `display:table-column;-elements` in it - and floating doesn't make any sense in that case.  ***[more info](http://www.css4you.de/display.html)***